# Is there a equivalent of igraph for MATLAB?

Tags: networking, matlab

Hi
I am looking for igraph possibly something similar for MATLAB to compute common network paramerers like clustering coefficient,
Thank YOU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the Matlab interface to the Boost Graph Library, which includes clustering coefficient, minimum spanning tree, shortest paths, etc.

http://www.stanford.edu/~dgleich/programs/matlab_bgl/
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10922